# Understanding Optimized Logical Plan

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839910/rewrite-logicalplan-to-push-down-udf-from-aggregate) and I'm trying to reproduce the problem.

However I get a completely deifferent optimized plan than the op's one.

Op's code:

```
spark.udf.register("inc", (x: Long) => x + 1)
val df = spark.sql("select sum(inc(vals)) from data")
df.explain(true)
df.show()
```

Op's optimized plan:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [sum(inc(vals#4L)) AS sum(inc(vals))#7L]
+- LocalRelation [vals#4L]
```

My code:

```
val df1 = spark.read
  .option("sep", "\t")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("D:/playground/pylearner.tsv")
    .withColumn("Month_year",trim($"Month_year"))

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("pylearner")

df1.show()

spark.udf.register("inc", (x: Long) => x + 1)
val df = spark.sql("select sum(inc(ID)) from pylearner")
df.explain(true)
df.show()
```

My optimized plan:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [sum(if (isnull(cast(ID#10 as bigint))) null else UDF:inc(cast(ID#10 as bigint))) AS sum(UDF:inc(cast(ID as bigint)))#45L]
+- Project [ID#10]
   +- Relation[ID#10,TYPE_ID#11,Month_year#12,Amount#13] csv
```

Comment: who is Op? Anyways, I have seen this too. I cached the df and then took the plan to get correct plan.

Comment: @Salim "op" means the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is converting a local `Seq[Long]` to a `DataFrame`. You are reading a csv file from disk.
Hence OP has a `LocalRelation`, while you have some extra stuff for reading in a csv, selecting the `ID` column out of it, and handling possibly missing (`null`) values.